# how to overwrite link_to in plugin

Tags: plugins, symfony1

I have written a Joomla Component to include Symfony applications, as part oft his I'd like ot package up some files on the symfony side in a plugin. I can't find a way to overwrite link_to from within a plugin. Essentially what my modified link_to does in wrap the link into a Joomla request if called from the Joomla component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should created a copy of UrlHelper and save it in your with another name, say UrlCustomHelper. Inside your code instead of using use_helper('Url') you use use_helper('UrlCustom').

You don't get to overwrite it like you do with a method of a inherited class.

Comment: Hmm, thats not really much better than copying a modified UrlHelper into the application/appname/lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

Either you copy the entire UrlHelper.php file with your modifications as you suggest, or you define a function with another name. There really aren't any other alternatives.

```
function joomla_link_to(...)
{
  ...
  return link_to(...);
}
```